# How to get description from a url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, google-chrome-extension, metadata

Hello I am creating a chrome extension and need to get the description, if any from the url. Tried looking for example but they seem to only work for hard data url that been entered. I get my url from my **content.js** -->

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  url: window.location.href
})
```

I would like to see how I would get the description/meta tag from that url at the moment. Any tips or solutions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Though `document.head`

You might want to try description first if found good, else look for the `og:` or `twitter:` tags.

```
// title
document.head.querySelector('title').innerText

// normal description meta tag
document.head.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').getAttribute('content')

// twitter:
document.head.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:description"]').getAttribute('content')

// og:
document.head.querySelector('meta[name="og:description"]').getAttribute('content')
```

Comment: When I put document.head.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').getAttribute('content'), I was given an type error of "Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null.." Would I put my url somewhere specific? @Lawrence Cherone

Comment: as said you would need to check it exists (hardly any sites use description any more), split up the line i.e remove `.getAttribute('content')` and check `querySelector` didn't return null, if is null try `twitter:`, if that's null try `og:`.. when not null use getAttribute